# Switch and Hide TabBarItems

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have an iPhone application that is setup as follows:

- UITabBarController
- CustomViewControllerLogin (UIViewController)
- UINavigationController
- - CustomViewController1 (UIViewController)
- - CustomViewController2 (UIViewController)
- CustomViewControllerLogout (UIViewController)

How do I switch to CustomViewController1, when the user clicks the Login button on CustomViewControllerLogin?

I also, need to "hide" CustomViewControllerLogin and "show" CustomViewControllerLogout?

Thanks in advance!!!
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your approach doesn't seem to be the most fortunate one to me.

What you could do is to replace the `UITabBarController` with a `UINavigationController` and go with the following approach:

- present your CustomViewControllerLogin modally. You can use something like this:

`[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:instanceOf CustomViewControllerLogin animated:YES];`

- set the rootViewController in the navigationController to be your CustomViewController1
- in your CustomViewControllerLogin, once the login is done successfully, dismiss the CustomViewControllerLogin using the following:

`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

- when this gets executed, your CustomViewController1 will be displayed. Do your app logic here and have a "Logout" button. You could put it on the navigation bar, on the right side for example.
- when the user taps on this logout button, you do the same as you did for the login:

`[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:instanceOf CustomViewControllerLogout animated:YES];`

I have seen a lot of apps where the UITabBarController is abused for purposes that it wasn't intended for. See for example [this](http://carpeaqua.com/2009/07/08/die-you-damn-dirty-tab-bar/) article.

Comment: Hi Stelian,

First thanks for your time.  It is appreciated!!!

I agree that TabBarController can be abused, but I do have separate information types that I would like to organize with the TabBarController.

I was hoping that like in Microsoft Access' Tab Control you can say something like: tab1.visible = False.

Any idea how to go about this?

P.S., you gave me a lot of food for thought about re-organizing to eliminate the TabBarController, but I want to continue to understand this before changing direction.

Jason

Comment: Hi Stelian,  I just wanted to let you know that your suggestion really helped me to think about the organization of my application differently.  I have incorporated Model views now to handle gathering the credentials of the user, which lead me to under delegation (through the use of @protocol, which is really cool).  Thanks!